# How do I get object from the clientside using RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Currently, I'm using rabbitmq to create a distributed system.

My goal is send the object from IOS(RabbitMQ) to the serverside(RabbitMQ) then only do a fanout to all the subscribers of the queue

[image]

I wrote the server and the client already

**Client - The publisher**

```
@IBAction func bookTripClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        if let user_id = keychain["id"] {
            print("Attempting to connect to local RabbitMQ broker")
            let conn = RMQConnection(uri: amqURL, delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
            conn.start()
            let ch = conn.createChannel()
            let q = ch.queue("book")

        ch.defaultExchange().publish(user_id.data(using: .utf8), routingKey: q.name)
            print(user_id)

        }
    }
```

The client will click a button then it will send the message, but I'm confused at the part on how to get the objects that I just sent to the server.

**Server**

```
var open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost');

var q = "book"

// Publisher
open.then(function(conn) {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
  return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
    return ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(JSON.stringify("How do I get the object?")));
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

**Client - Consumers**

```
func receive() {
        print("Attempting to connect to local RabbitMQ broker") // Print the message
        let conn = RMQConnection(uri: amqURL, delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
        conn.start()

        let ch = conn.createChannel() // Create the channel name on the rabbitMQ Server
        let q = ch.queue("book") // Queue the message in the channel || the name of the channel / queue
        print("Waiting for the messages")
        q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
            print("Received \(String(data: message.body, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)")

        })
    }
```

The reason Why I need it to go through the server is because I want to Save the object later. I can't just remove the serverside and it would work just fine between client to client, but I need the JSON object to save it on the database in the future

So the main question is How do I get the JSON object on the serverside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confused between RMQ server and the node server that you are running. Your node server is not the same as the RMQ server. The messages you publish don't go through the node server you have.

You are publishing messages on the queue on the node server. Instead, you have to listen on the queue to get the messages on the node server side. Then, your node server will actually act like one of the **client - consumers** that are listening on a fanout queue, except in node.

Comment: So technically on the node server side, I just need to create a consumer option?

Comment: Thanks for the answer